# Relation to find the last standing person in a circle. Possible variant of Josephus problem

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

Consider a set of N people standing in a circle, we kill the first person, spare the second, kill the third person  and so on.. Find the last standing person in the circle.

I think this might be the same as the [Josephus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)  problem but I'm not entirely sure and would appreciate any insight on approaching the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the $k=2$ case of the Josephus problem, but you are off by one from the classic formulation because you kill the first instead of the second.  Take the classic solution, then subtract one from the last one standing to account for that.  If the classic last standing is $1$, it will be $N$ as the subtraction should be done $\bmod N$

Comment: Do you mean to say the relation would look like `f(n,2){= if(n==1) return 0 else return  (((f(n-1,k)+k-1)%n)+1)-1}`. If not, could you add the relation to your answer as well?

Comment: I would just use the usual calculation until you get the final result, then subtract $1$.  It looks to me like you may subtract $1$ more than once along the way.  Use the usual $f(n,2)$, then let $g(n,2)=(f(n,2)-1)\%N$